# How do i calculate the confidence interval of a simple slope?

Tags: regression, mathematical-statistics, confidence-interval, spss

I have got the following information about variable a:

simple slope of the high level of A = -0.2437579

standard error of the high level of A = 2.197419

t-value for the high level of A = -0.1109292

Mean of A   2.693911
Standard Deviation of a 0.617316

Degrees of freedom is 302

Can someone plz help me and tell me how i can or need to calculate the 95% confidence interval with the aformentioned information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to be clear you don't know how many samples were used to calculate the slope, correct?

The first thing you need to do it calculate the degrees of freedom of the slope calculation (in simple linear regression this is the number of samples minus 2)

The formula for the t-value for the high level of A is 
$t=\frac{A}{s_E\sqrt{df}}$

From your information $A=-0.2437579$, $s_E=2.197419$, $t=-0.1109292$

Therefore

$-0.1109292=\frac{-0.2437579}{2.197419\sqrt{df}}$

Rearranging you get $df=1$ so the slope was calculated from 3 samples.

Now to calculate the confidence interval of $A$ use the t distribution with 1 degree of freedom. I trust you know how to use tables to find a t value. For a two tailed distribution with $df=1$ the t-value for 95% coverage is $12.7$

The 95% confidence interval is $\hat{A}\pm t\times s_E= -0.2437579 \pm 12.7\times 2.197419=[-27.66,28.15]$

The confidence interval is very large because there sample size for the regression was 3.

Comment: Thank you very much!! Sorry I forgot to mention that the degrees of freedom of the slope is 302. Could you plz tell me what the confidence interval is? I want to double check if my outcome is similar to yours.